# Help me with bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I had ubuntu 16.04 alongside with win10 , everything was normal .then I installed ubuntu 17.10 on the same ubuntu 16.04 partition and formatted it.
now when I boot , I go directly to windows 10 instead of booting into grub menu.
However I managed to access the ubuntu install by pressing shift restart in windows and select the boot device . 
Now I want to have grub again and select which os to boot into 
note : I see 2 ubuntu entries in the windows boot selection if I shift restart .
so help me please , I am new to linux and don't know where the bootloaders are or which one goes

Comment: What brand/model system? Often better to stay with LTS as with 17.10 you will soon have to upgrade to 18.04 LTS. May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I actually want to add Grub again manually or fix the ubuntu install or reinstal it while I can do it alongeside windows and still can choose my partition